# Delete double quotes in csv bash

Tags: bash, csv, command-line

I’m having the following issue:

I have the csv file with data inside looks like this:

```
“1,””name””,””surname””,””age””,””city”””
“2,””Peter””,””Parker””,””30””,””NY”””
“3,””marry””,””Jane””,””30””,””NY”””
```

Is it possible using bash to delete the first and the last double quote from each row and then first and last double quote from each field in it?
To get something like this:

```
1,”name”,”surname”,”age”,”NY”
3,”marry”,”Jane”,”30”,”NY”
```

I would be grateful for some hints. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: Are these " or ”? Also the end lines have three not two.

Comment: These are  " , and yes at the end there are three of them, but as you can see the first field with number does not have the closing one

Comment: What happened to the second line?

Comment: That looks like a single-column CSV file where each field itself was a row from a CSV file. What generated the file?

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:

```
echo '"1,""name"",""surname"",""age"",""city"""' | sed "s/\"\"/\"/g" | sed 's/^\"\(.*\)\"$/\1/'
```

**OUPUT**

[image]

You can take that, adjust it to run over a file, line by line (instead of the first `echo` and output into another file

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your input looks like this:

```
"1,""name"",""surname"",""age"",""city"""
"2,""Peter"",""Parker"",""30"",""NY"""
"3,""marry"",""Jane"",""30"",""NY"""
```

Note the actual `"`'s not the `””` in your code:

You can then sed multiple things and chain them together e.g.

```
sed -e "s/\"\"\"/\"/g" -e "s/\"\"/\"/g" input.txt
```

This first replaces the triple quotes `"""`, reducing them to double quotes `""` and then reduces them further.

Final output:

```
"1,"name","surname","age","city"
"2,"Peter","Parker","30","NY"
"3,"marry","Jane","30","NY"
```

If you have special characters then simply replace them in the code e.g.:

```
$ cat input.txt
“1,””name””,””surname””,””age””,””city”””
“2,””Peter””,””Parker””,””30””,””NY”””
“3,””marry””,””Jane””,””30””,””NY”””
$ sed -e "s/\”\”\”/\”/g" -e "s/\”\”/\”/g" input.txt
“1,”name”,”surname”,”age”,”city”
“2,”Peter”,”Parker”,”30”,”NY”
“3,”marry”,”Jane”,”30”,”NY”
```

Though I think this input is a transpose error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/;s/"\+/"/g' file
```

The first substitution removes the outer double quote on the whole line.

The second substitution replaces the parameter quote to only one double quote.